# Make SEDE graphing easier

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, graphs

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is generally great, but the one thing that keeps bugging me about it is its graphing support. The given example of graphing in the SEDE help is graphing the number of posts for each score. Currently, to achieve that graph, the query is this:

[image]

I'd like the UI to change so that making a graph is easier: perhaps something like this:

[image]

Closer in, for those hard of hearing who can't see that image properly:

[image]

This would make it immensely easier to use graphs on SEDE, especially for non-programmers who've just picked up a little SQL to grab some data.

Comment: Across all the tools I have used, it's common that first column -> X axis, rest -> Y axis. Does this convention need an extra UI element?